# A conditional statement within a Partition By In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a query that has a running count (timesRaced_byEvent) to show how many times a horse has run a particular event. My problem is the TimesWon_byEvent, where I want that field to show a running count of occasions where a horse won (placed 1st) for a particular event, but as you can see I'm not quite there....
[image]

```
select #temp2.Horse
    , #temp2.RaceLength
    , #temp2.Position
    , #temp2.RDIndex
    , count(#temp2.RaceLength) over (Partition by #temp2.Horse, #temp2.RaceLength order by #temp2.Horse, #temp2.RaceLength, #temp2.RDIndex desc) - 1 as TimesRaced_byEvent
    , TimesWon_ByEvent
from #temp2 
Left join 
(
    Select Horse
        , RDIndex
        , RaceLength
        , count(RaceLength) over (Partition by Horse, RaceLength order by Horse, RaceLength,RDIndex desc) - 1 as TimesWon_ByEvent
    from #temp2
    where Position = '1'
) win on #temp2.Horse = Win.Horse 
    and #temp2.RDIndex = Win.RDIndex 
    and #temp2.RaceLength = Win.RaceLength
order by #temp2.RDIndex
```

Comment: Are events only defined by the horse's name and the length? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: No, they are also defined by UR_RDIndex - which is an index as to when the horse ran, ie where it is 1 it is the most recent occasion where the horse was running, 2 the previous time, etc etc

Comment: [edit] your question. **explain** your data and what it means. Don't expect people to divine your meaning purely from sample data and a query that *clearly doesn't do what you want it to do* (if it did, you wouldn't be asking a question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you seem to want:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (partition by horse, racelength order by rdindex desc) - 1) as timesRacedbyEvent,
       sum(case when ur_position = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by order, racelength order by rdindex desc) as 
from #temp2 t;
```

I'm a little confused by the column names.  You seem to equate `racelength` with "event".  But this should do what you are asking.

Comment: Perfect, I now know how to use a condition within a Partition.... just transposing your logic into my table...sum(case when ur_position = '1' then 1 else 0 end) over (Partition by #temp2.Horse,#temp2.UR_RaceLength order by #temp2.Horse,#temp2.UR_RaceLength,#temp2.UR_RDIndex desc)
Thanks